# Processing Latency

Tags: cloud, iot, latency, fog

Hello Everybody please help me ,

I would like to compute the processing latency over different layer in the network , especialy on the cloud server. I want a mathematical function to compute the processing latency , I looked for the solution but I found nothing

Comment: This question is problematic for two reasons: first it concerns networking rather than development, but more fundamentally it is a request for an algorithm, which is not within the mission of stack exchange overall.

Answer (score 0):

Latency = sum of delays.

More specific formulas are only possible for more specific questions. In an applied setting where you want to know the actual performance of a system, **latency is measured, not computed**. Real-world latencies tend to be statistical distributions rather than numbers, so the most relevant formulas may be for statistical analysis of the measurements (say, the 99th-percentile latency).

A formula can make sense when you know all the steps along the way. The [Network Latency Calculator](http://www.rfwireless-world.com/calculators/Network-Latency-Calculator.html) expresses latency as the sum of the time it takes a packet to travel between a source and destination (most relevant over long distances) and the time it takes the sending system to prepare the packet:

[image]

And that is just in one direction. This might not seem relevant to processing latency, yet it illustrates a fraction of the complexity that could be involved if this unknown cloud server makes calls to a database or other service. Uncertainty around even one variable throws the result into question. So the question is what you really need to measure.

- If interested in latency from a user perspective, use client-side tools that analyze times between request and response.
- If measuring internal steps inside code you control, log event timestamps or the differences between them.
- If looking for more granular results across cloud systems, access cloud logs that track events across multiple systems.